# Returning numbers included in a number

Tags: number-theory, functions, algorithms

The title is not clear what is my problem. I have one number which is the sum of (total) some numbers and I want to know what numbers are included in that number. I have some permissions (as you see below) and I just get one number and I need to return permissions a user has.

```
1:  "Permission One",
2:  "permission Two",
4:  "permission Three",
8:  "permission Four",
16: "permission Five"
```

I just get one number (from the server-side) and I need a function that returns what permissions this user has.

For example, when I get `9`, it means:

```
8+1
```

Or when I get `7` it should return:

```
4+2+1
```

Comment: For each permission, perform "bitwise and" of its code with the value

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Can you please explain more

Comment: Why can't you just convert to binary and look at it placewise to see each permission? E.g. permission one $= 1_2$, permission two $= 10_2$, permission one and two $= 11_2$, and so forth.

Comment: Let's start with the function you say you've written. I'd suggest you summarise it (the algorithm) in your question. That way people can gauge how best to help you.

Comment: @Deepak Please check the answer, I edited the question + added my own algorithm and live demo

Comment: I haven't coded in forever. Your algorithm looks like a rudimentary binary long division implementation, but you can make things a lot simpler by just using the capabilities computers already have to calculate in binary. Let's start with this: do you understand binary? Can you list the binary representation of every integer from $1$ to $16$ inclusive? Anyone who can code should already have some familiarity with binary.

Comment: After you make this list, look carefully at Hagen von Eitzen's post. Do you understand a bitwise AND? It's a computer function in many languages, and it's very useful for looking at binary places (individual bits).

Comment: @Deepak thanks for your solution, I could do it by the bitwise operation, but I am still not sure how does it work! for example for 5, if we say: 1&5 =>1 and 5&5 =>5... I am just kind of confused about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be easily done by bitwise AND operation, JavaScript bitwise AND operator symbol is `&`, and here is how you can do it:

```
function checkRoles(roleToCheck, rolesChecksum){
   return roleToCheck == (roleToCheck & rolesChecksum);
}
//For example, rolesChecksum is 10:
checkRoles(1, 10) //Returns false
checkRoles(2, 10) //Returns true
checkRoles(8, 10) //Returns true
```