# Monotonicity of quadratic function at its vertex?

Tags: functions

In my school text book, It say that the quadratic function is increasing and decreasing at some intervals based on the function, however both intervals didn't include the vertex and it was't discussed at all.

Should the vertex be constant because its slop is equal to zero? Or should I just leave it and not include it in any interval like the text book proposed? And how come I can leave it while  it is from the domain of the function?

**Example:**

Discuss the monotonicity of the function $f(x)= {x}^{2}$:

$f(x) \text{  increases at }x \in ]0,\infty[$

$f(x) \text{  decreases at }x \in ]-\infty,0[$

As you can see they didn't include zero in any of the intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should the vertex be constant because its slop is equal to zero?

Monotonicity is generally defined on a subset of the domain which includes multiple points e.g. an interval, so (again, in general) it doesn't make sense to refer to monotonicity *at* one single point.

(*As a side note, it* does *make sense for differentiable functions to associate the derivative at a point with the "rate of change" in some sense, and it's common to say that* $f(x)$ *is* increasing *at* $x_0$ *if* $f'(x) \gt 0$ *however that's more of a casual language license, and also it's a sufficient condition but not a necessary one, for example* $f(x) = x^3$ *is* strictly *increasing on* $\mathbb{R}$ *but* $f'(0)=0$.)

Back to the question, what the book says is correct. However, it is equally correct, and in fact a stronger statement, to say that $f(x)$ is *strictly* decreasing on $(-\infty,0\,]$ and strictly increasing on $[\,0,\infty)$ where *both* intervals include $0$.

> And how come I can leave it while it is from the domain of the function?

There is no requirement (or guarantee) that the intervals of monotonicity cover the entire domain.

For example $f(x) = x \cdot sin \frac{1}{x}$ for $x \ne 0$ with $f(0)=0$ is a continuous function which is not monotonic on *any* interval that includes $0$. For an example of a discontinuous function which is not monotonic on *any* interval consider the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thanks, do you mind telling me why you didn't use a square bracket on the infinity and negative infinity $(-\infty,0\,]$?

Comment: Infinities are not real numbers ($\pm \infty \not \in \mathbb{R}$) so they can't belong to a real interval. The notation $x \in (-\infty,0]$ simply means $x \le 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you would choose to put zero in one of the two intervals, which one would you choose?

At the vertex the slope is zero, so the function is neither increasing nor decreasing.

Comment: Can you please answer this question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1930095/322103? I am not good at math and you can help me