# Are there any increasing or decreasing intervals for 1) $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ and 2) $f(x)=2+x^{2/3}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, applications

My book states both of the functions 1 and 2 have no intervals.
for 1) $f'(x)=(1/3)x^{-2/3}$ which is >0 for every real value of x
and 2) $f'(x)=(2/3)x^{-1/3}$ which is <0 for (-∞,0) and >0 for (0,∞)

but both of the first derivatives are undefined at x=0.

So, can we say that  $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ is increasing on (-∞, 0) U (0, +∞)

and  $f(x)=2+x^{2/3}$ is decreasing on (-∞,0) and increasing on (0,∞)

thus we get intervals. Am i correct?

Answer (score 0):

1) Correct. The fact that the derivative at $0$ is undefined doesn't preclude monotonicity. You know that $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ is strictly increasing on the open intervals $(-\infty, 0)$, $(0, \infty)$, and also know that $f(0) \lt f(x)$ for $\forall x \gt 0$ and $f(0) \gt f(x)$ for $\forall x \lt 0$. This makes $f(x)$ strictly increasing on the whole $\mathbb{R} = (-\infty,\infty)$.

2) Technically correct, but both intervals of monotonicity should include $\{0\}$, as $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$ and strictly decreasing on $(-\infty,0]$. See previous step why.

---

[ *EDIT* ]  The question was edited since I posted my answer. After the latest edit, my former `1) Correct.` would rather now be `1) Technically correct, but...`. It *is* technically correct that $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is increasing on $(-\infty,0) \cup(0,\infty)$ but that's a weaker statement than $\sqrt[3]{x}$ being increasing on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$. Just like for example saying that $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is increasing on $(1,2) \cup (3,5)$ is technically correct, but is not the best or most relevant assessment of the monotonicity of $\sqrt[3]{x}$.

Comment: For 2),you have included x=0 on both increasing and decreasing interval. So particularly at x=0 we get a spike in the curve and how can we determine whether the function is increasing or decreasing at x=0 since first derivative is undefined at x=0.

Comment: how can a function both increase and decrease at a same point? in reference to x=0 for second function.

Comment: @ManishYadav A function increases or decreases on an interval not at *one* point. You may want to read my answer to a similar question at [Monotonicity of quadratic function at its vertex?](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2011385/291201).

Comment: i mean to say that the particular point is contained in an arbitrary interval

Comment: @ManishYadav Any particular point can be contained in many intervals. This doesn't change the fact that, as I said, `a function increases or decreases on an interval not at one point`. Do you disagree that $2+\sqrt[3]{x^2}$ is *strictly* increasing on $[0,\infty)$ and ***also*** *strictly* decreasing on $(-\infty,0]$?

Comment: I agree to all the things you said, except the existence of x=0 on both the intervals. Your statement says at x=0, the second function is both increasing and decreasing which is impossible. According to me, it should have been strictly decreasing on (−∞,0) and  strictly increasing on (0,+∞).

Comment: @ManishYadav Again, you insist on considering monotonicity *at* a point. Consider that the very definition of monotonicity requires $2$ distinct points. Back to the issue at hand, if you disagree that $2 + \sqrt[3]{x^2}$ is strictly increasing on the half-closed interval $[0,\infty)$ then please make your case why that's wrong, starting from the definition of monotonicity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48920/discussion-between-manish-yadav-and-dxiv).

Comment: Sorry, I don't do chats. Nothing personal or question related, just that I don't generally chat at all.