# Exact Expression for the n-th Derivative

Tags: combinatorics, derivatives, stirling-numbers

The question asks me to find an exact expression for the n-th derivative of the function $f(x) = e^{e^{x}}$.

I noticed a pattern and claimed that the derivative could be expressed as 
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}[e^{e^{x}}] = S_{1,n}e^xe^{e^{x}} + S_{2,n} e^{2x}e^{e^{x}}+...+S_{n-1,n}e^{(n-1)x}e^{e^{x}}+S_{n,n}e^{nx}e^{e^{x}}$$ 
where $S_{n,k}$ is the Stirling number of the second kind.

Now I have tried to prove that this is the case by using induction and have easily shown that the base case is true. I am having problem with trying to show the inductive step.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer and will use the notation ${n\brace k}$ for the Stirling numbers of the second kind. Here’s the induction step.

Suppose that

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(e^{e^x}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n{n\brace k}e^{kx}e^{e^x}\;;$$

then

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}\left(e^{e^x}\right)&=\sum_{k=1}^n{n\brace k}\left(e^{kx}\cdot e^xe^{e^x}+ke^{kx}e^{e^x}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n{n\brace k}\left(e^{k+1}x+ke^{kx}\right)e^{e^x}\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}{n\brace{k-1}}e^{kx}e^{e^x}+\sum_{k=1}^nk{n\brace k}e^{kx}e^{e^x}\\
&\overset{(1)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\left({n\brace{k-1}}+k{n\brace k}\right)e^{kx}e^{e^x}\\
&\overset{(2)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}{{n+1}\brace k}e^{kx}e^{e^x}\;.
\end{align*}$$

$(1)$ holds because ${n\brace 0}=0={n\brace{n+1}}$, and $(2)$ uses a standard recurrence satisfied by the Stirling numbers of the second kind.

Comment: How did you write the stirling numbers here? I prefer your notation too but couldn't figure out how to express it your way

Comment: @Dylan: For ${n\brace k}$ use `{{n}\brace{k}}`. (By the way, if you right-click on an expression, then select `Show Math As` followed by `TeX Commands`, you’ll be able to see how the expression was coded.)

Comment: {n \brace k} is enough: ${n \brace k} $.

Comment: @marty: I know that. If you check, you’ll find that I actually used it in my answer. But if the upper or lower number is compound, the extra braces are needed, and it was simplest to include them in the illustrative example: using them is never wrong even when it’s unnecessary.

Comment: @Dylan: You’re very welcome!

Comment: can you please define ${ n \brace k }$??, thank u very much dr Scott

Comment: @ILoveMath:That's a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: Could you please help to answer this http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1930095/322103?