# Finding the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{4^n+9^n}$ using L'Hopital's rule

Tags: limits, functions, limits-without-lhopital

The problem was to find

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{4^n+9^n}$$

So after a couple tries what I did was to take the natural logarithm of the limit so

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{4^n+9^n}=L$$
$$\downarrow$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(\sqrt[n]{4^n+9^n})=\ln L$$
$$\downarrow$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln({4^n+9^n})}{n}=\ln L$$
$$\downarrow L'Hopital$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{4^n\ln 4+9^n\ln 9}{4^n+9^n}=\ln L$$

And there I'm stuck. I checked in Wolfram and $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ of both the initial function and the one after L'Hopital's rule is $9$. ($\ln L=\ln 9\rightarrow L=9$).

I'd like to know how to find the limit from the last step I made, and if there's a more elegant way of solving the problem (which I'm sure there is), maybe without using L'Hôpital's rule.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't have to use L'hopital, then have a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955393/limit-of-the-sequence-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn4n-5n/1955407#1955407).

Comment: In the last step, just split the thing you have on the left hand side.

Comment: Easier to use $2\cdot 9^n> 4^n+9^n> 9^n$ and apply the squeeze theorem.

Comment: [$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{x^n+y^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80340/convergence-of-sqrtnxnyn-for-x-y-0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'Hospital is a detour.

If you put a factor of $9$ outside the root sign, we get
$$ \sqrt[n]{4^n+9^n} = 9 \cdot \sqrt[n]{(4/9)^n+1} $$

Here $(4/9)^n$ goes to $0$, and taking an $n$th root yields something even closer to $1$ than $(4/9)^n+1$.

Comment: Could you please help to answer this ? http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1930095/322103

Answer (score 3):

Divide top and bottom by $9^n$ to get:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(4/9)^n\ln 4+\ln 9}{(4/9)^n+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{4^n\ln 4+9^n\ln 9}{4^n+9^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(4/9)^n\ln 4+\ln 9}{(4/9)^n+1}=\ln 9$$